# How to prove that if a number is divisible by two other numbers, then it is divisible by their product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I would like to prove if $a \mid n$ and $b \mid n$ then $a \cdot b \mid n$ for $\forall n \ge a \cdot b$ where $a, b, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

I'm stuck.
$n = a \cdot k_1$
$n = b \cdot k_2$
$\therefore a \cdot k_1 = b \cdot k_2$

EDIT: so for [fizzbuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) it wouldn't make sense to check to see if a number is divisible by 15 to see if it's divisible by both 3 and 5?

Comment: You are possibly thinking of the following: if $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n$ and $a,b$ are relatively prime, then $ab\mid n$.

Comment: Re: edit, yes it would make sense because $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime (have no common factor except $1$).  See my previous comment.

Comment: @David ya that's what I was thinking of. so it needs to be a condition a and b are relatively prime?

Comment: It is a sufficient condition that $a,b$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are possibly thinking of the following: if $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n$ and $a,b$ are relatively prime (have no common factor except 1), then $ab\mid n$.

**Proof**.  We have $n=ak$ and $n=bl$ for some integers $k,l$.  Therefore $b\mid ak$; since $a,b$ are relatively prime this implies $b\mid k$, so $k=bm$, so $n=abm$; therefore $ab\mid n$.

Re: edit, yes this would make sense because $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime.

Comment: how do you know b | ak ?

Comment: Because $n=ak$, see the first equation in the proof.

Comment: How to formally prove that: b∣ak; since a,b are relatively prime this implies b∣k?

Comment: @user394691 Since $a,b$ are relatively prime we have $ax+by=1$ for some integers $x,y$.  Hence $akx+bky=k$; and $b\mid akx$ (because $b\mid ak$) and $b\mid bky$ (obviously); so $b\mid akx+bky$, that is, $b\mid k$.

Answer (score 8):

This is false. For example, 3 | 30 and 6 | 30, but their product, 18, does not divide 30 even though $3 \times 6 < 30$.

Answer (score 2):

Updated:  The edited version is still not true.  At least two counterexamples in the comments below.

Prior counterexample:  This is not true.  $12|36$ and $9|36$, but $12\cdot9 = 108 \not | 36$.

Comment: We misread the question this isn't a counter example.

Comment: @GitGud . . . however, replacing $36$ by $36+12\times9$, that is, $144$, does give a counterexample.

Comment: Or $(a,b,n)=(4,6,36)$. It's hard to believe someone up voted this when my comment says this isn't a counter example.

Comment: @GitGud:  So, ..., I reread and reread the problem.  (1) it has not changed and (2) it still claims a falsehood.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes and your answer still isn't a counter example to statement in the OP's question.

Comment: @GitGud:  I misclaim.  The problem statement has changed.  A comma has been altered.

Comment: @EricTowers Not according to the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/777691/revisions), but it could be that the edit was done in the first five minutes of the question being asked, in which case it wouldn't appear in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ a,b\mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid n\!\!\!\overset{\ \ \ \large \times\, (a,b)}\iff ab\mid n(a,b),\, $ which is not equivalent to $\,ab\mid n\ $

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $x a + y b = 1$ for some integers $x, y$ (Bezout's identity).
Then
$$
n = k_1 a \overset{\times yb}{\Leftrightarrow} (yb)n = (yk_1) ab\\
n = k_2 b \overset{\times xa}{\Leftrightarrow} (xa)n = (xk_2) ab
$$
Adding the two equations together we get $(xa + yb)n = (yk_1 + x k_2)ab \Leftrightarrow n = k (ab)$, where $k = yk_1 + xk_2$ is an integer. This proves that $ab \mid n$.